# NUnit Throws exceptions but still passes

Tags: azure-pipelines, nunit, .net-4.7.2

I am running a new project with mstest with NUnit In Azure Devops pipeline. Locally No errors in output even when running it in command line: "vstest.console.exe"
When I Push my commit to the git branch and run the pipeline the Test still pass but when I look at the logs I see some exception in the output.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies

I can choose to ignore them but that usually ends ups giving us trouble in the future.
I am targeting net 4.7.2 this is because of a legacy project before we are able to upgrade. and I am using NUnit.3.13.3 & NUnit3TestAdapter.4.2.1.

**My YAML:**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\NetLink.Test.dll
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**MY PIPELINE OUTPUT:**

> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2286691Z Exception
> NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException,    Exception thrown executing tests
> in D:\a\1\s\src\NetLink.Test\obj\Release\NetLink.Test.dll
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2287621Z An exception occurred in the driver while
> loading tests. 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2340151Z    at
> NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver
> driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2341837Z    at
> NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage()
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2342578Z    at
> NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2343323Z    at
> NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.Explore(TestFilter filter)
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2344047Z    at
> NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.Explore(TestFilter filter)
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2345237Z    at
> NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnitEngine.NUnitEngineAdapter.Explore(TestFilter
> filter) in
> D:\repos\NUnit\nunit3-vs-adapter\src\NUnitTestAdapter\NUnitEngine\NUnitEngineAdapter.cs:line
> 88 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2346984Z    at
> NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnit3TestExecutor.RunAssembly(String
> assemblyPath, IGrouping`2 testCases, TestFilter filter) in D:\repos\NUnit\nunit3-vs-adapter\src\NUnitTestAdapter\NUnit3TestExecutor.cs:line 275 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2349381Z InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2350958Z File name: 'nunit.framework, Version=3.13.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2352646Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2355042Z    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2357386Z    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2358710Z    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2360814Z    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2362021Z    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2363179Z    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2364023Z    at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] args) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2364626Z    at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(String testAssemblyPath, IDictionary`2 settings) 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2365476Z
> at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadDriver(IFrameworkDriver
> driver, String testFile, TestPackage subPackage)
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2365997Z WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned
> OFF. 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2366517Z To enable assembly bind failure
> logging, set the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2367098Z Note: There is some performance penalty
> associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2367650Z To turn this feature off, remove the
> registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> 2022-09-06T18:32:55.2368120Z NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution
> complete

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems the exception occurs when loading tests, so no tests are run.

In this case, the [syntax of the VSTest runner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines#syntax) may be helpful.

It has two options you can use:

- `failOnMinTestsNotRun`: Fail the task if a minimum number of tests are not run. Default: False.
- `minimumExpectedTests`: Optional. Use when failOnMinTestsNotRun = true. Minimum # of tests. Default: '1'.

So I would suggest updating your task as follows:

```yaml
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\NetLink.Test.dll
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
```

Which I think would likely have the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response. All the test do pass, so this wouldn't help. I did just add this just to make sure. All tests pass but I get this Exception.

Comment: @greektreat are you sure that your tests are running? The exception in your question appears to indicate an error on loading tests, and I don't see any output in that message indicating that tests have run, and the output appears to indicate an error when loading tests.

Comment: @greektreat you may want to explore the `otherConsoleOptions` argument where you can provide other options that `vstest.console.exe` uses. Using this you may be able to specify `FailWhenNoTestsFound` as an option, for example. From the VSTest documentation: "By default, the command returns 0 when it exits normally, even if no tests are discovered. If you want to return a non-zero value if no tests are discovered, use /FailWhenNoTestsFound." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022

Comment: Sorry I think my question may not convey what I am concerned for. All my tests cases pass properly why is there an exception being thrown in the output. how do I Stop the exception from happening since everything still works.